# How to prevent that a tab opens in a new window in firefox 3.5

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

On Firefox 3.5, when I drag down a tab, it opens in a new widnow (I suppose is the same as clicking with the rigth button on a tab and selecting *Open In A New Tab*).

If it isn't possible to avoid it, at least haw can I make the tab go back to the original window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Download bug489729](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12276) (Disable detach and tear off tab) 1.2 [Mozilla Add-ons]

Once you’ve installed the experimental Firefox extension, you’ll need to open up Add-ons from the Tools menu, and then choose “Disable detach tab” from the extension options page.

[image]

[The change should be immediate, no more detaching tabs.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2082/week-in-geek-the-disable-firefox-3.5-tab-tearing-edition/)

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the Plug-In called [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/). It has a bunch of options to tweak the behavior of the tabs in Firefox.  I find this tool is one of my "Must Have" firefox plug ins. It provides the ability to control the behavior of opening new windows as well as a number of other handy features like being able to move tabs around from one window to another or to re-arrange the order they appear in the current window.  Lifehacker named this as one of the "10 Must Have Firefox extensions".

Here is a list of the features...

- **Duplicates tabs**

  - Opens a new tab with the same page and back/forward history
- **Controls tab focus**

  - Allows the user to choose whether new tabs will be selected when created by various events (such as linking, opening bookmarks, etc.)
- **JavaScript decompiling**

  - Allows JavaScript to be forced into a separate tab instead of a pop-up box, and allows the user to view the URL of the JavaScript page.
- **Changes handling of input**

  - Some clicks, points, and key-presses can be assigned new tab-related functions
- **Recovers closed tabs and windows**

  - Saves information about tabs and windows as they are closed, allowing the user to "undo" closing them, including retaining written information from the user (e.g. in a Wikipedia edit page)
- **Session Manager and Crash Recovery**

  - Similar to bookmarks, saves the current set of open windows and tabs (and associated history) on command and in preparation for a crash (see Session Saver extension)

While you are at it...You might as well install [colorful tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/) too!  You'll find it is helpful if you keep quite a few tabs open at once.

Comment: +1 for tab mix plus, it contains features that Firefox should have for tabbed browsing by default, including fixing this issue.

Comment: Thanks JT!  You have restored my faith in humanity :-P  
I was a bit disappointed to see a bug fix hack beat this one out knowing the differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Disable **Tab Tearing**.. [**The Disable Firefox 3.5 Tab Tearing Edition**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2082/week-in-geek-the-disable-firefox-3.5-tab-tearing-edition/)

Refers to the Firefox Addon -- [**bug489729 (Disable detach and tear off tab) 1.3**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12276)